How might students use “gstatic.com” to get around a Classwize filter?
I work in a public K12 school system. We are using a Chromebook management system (Classwize) to monitor the 2,500 Chromebooks we have in our building.
Many times students are finding ways to get around the filter and open up a tab to cheat. I run a report when I suspect this happening because it doesn't show on the teacher console but I am seeing many occurrences of gstatic.com on the report.
I suspect they are able to download something to hide the tabs from the teachers view.
Any one have any insight on how this is being done?

so its not at all surprising that you see lots of traffic to gstatic.com from chromebooks. I would be surprised if there was any google service that didn't use gstatic for one resource or another (for instance google search page or gmail). Can you see more about the requests than just the domain?

Accessing gstatic.com doesn’t suggest students are cheating. The best way to prevent cheating is to not allow these devices during a test. This seems like a human behavior problem rather than a technical problem.
